# modem.oqpskmod for BER

Tags: matlab, simulation

hi can anyone show how to use the modem.oqpskmod for BER. thanks!

```
    h = modem.oqpskmod
    y = modulate(h, values);
    g = modem.oqpskdemod(h)
    z = demodulate(g, y)
```

let's assume that i have array called values which contains only 1s and 0s.
my question is how would i calculate BER? of course if above my code is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_error_rate), you simply have to compute the number of incorrect bits and divide by the total number of transferred bits to get the bit error rate (BER). If `values` is the unmodulated input signal and `z` is the output signal after modulation and demodulation, you can compute it like this:

```
BER = sum(logical(values(:)-z(:)))/numel(values);
```

**EDIT:** I modified the above code just in case you run into two situations:

- If `z` has values other than 0 and 1.
- If `z` is a different size than `values` (i.e. row vector versus column vector).

I don't know if you are ever likely to come across these two situations, but better safe than sorry. ;)