# modem.oqpskmod - converting array of different values to array of 1s and 0s

Tags: matlab

hi i was doing the following in matlab

```
    values = [0;1;0;0;1;0;1;0];   % can contain only 0s and 1s 
    h = modem.oqpskmod; 
    y = modulate(h, values); 
    g = modem.oqpskdemod(h); 
    z = demodulate(g,y); 
    BER = sum(logical(values(:)-z(:)))/numel(values); % thanks to gnovice!
```

before calculating the BER, do you think that i have to convert the array z into array of 1s and 0s only... for example, my z may consist of 3s and 0s, then do i have to convert all numbers bigger than 0 to 1s and all 0s unchanged. so that at the end i get the correct comparison for the BER?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how you want to do the comparison of the input and output. [The code I gave you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179737/modem-oqpskmod-for-ber/2180055#2180055) for computing the BER will count *any* difference between the input and output as an error. So, a value of 3 for an output and a corresponding 1 for an input are counted as *different*.

If you want to compute the BER in another way, here are a couple more options you could use. Each of these assumes `values` contains only zeroes and ones:

- **Count any non-zero output value as a 1:** In this case, you would use the function [LOGICAL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/logical.html) to convert *any* non-zero value of `z` (i.e. the values 3, 0.5, -1, etc.) to a 1, leaving the values that are *exactly* zero unchanged:

  ```
  BER = sum(values(:)-logical(z(:)))/numel(values);
  ```
- **Count positive values as 1 and negative values as 0:** This solution just uses a comparison operator instead of [LOGICAL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/logical.html):

  ```
  BER = sum(values(:)-(z(:) > 0))/numel(values);
  ```

You may also want to try setting the `'OutputType'` property of the [`modem.oqpskdemod`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/comm/ref/modem.oqpskdemod.html) object to `'bit'` to ensure a binary output. Then you shouldn't have to do anything to `z`:

```
...
g = modem.oqpskdemod(h,'OutputType','bit'); 
z = demodulate(g,y);
BER = sum(values(:)-z(:))/numel(values);
```